# Convergence of $\sum (\ln(n))e^{-\sqrt{n}}$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, solution-verification

Study the convergence of  $\sum (\ln(n))e^{-\sqrt{n}}$.

---

I tried using the integral test, but ended up with some horrible integral. Then I decided to use the Cauchy condensation test and the ratio test.

By the Condensation test, the series converges iff $$\sum \frac{2^n \ln(2^n)}{e^{\sqrt{2^n}}}=\sum\frac{n2^n\ln(2)}{e^{(\sqrt{2})^n}}$$ converges.
Now, using the ratio test $$a_{n+1}/a_n=\frac{n+1}{n}\frac{2^{n+1}}{2^n}\frac{e^{(\sqrt{2})^n}}{e^{(\sqrt{2})^{n+1}}}$$
$$\approx \frac{2}{e^{(\sqrt{2})^{{n+1}}-(\sqrt{2})^n}}=\frac{2}{e^{{(\sqrt{2})^n}-(\sqrt{2}-1)}}\to 0.$$

Is my solution correct? Also, is there an easier way to prove this?

Comment: There is a slight problem. The condensation test can be applied for nonincreasing positive terms, or nonincreasing for $n\ge n_0.$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your solution seems correct. A different (I hesitate to say *simpler*) approach is to compare your series with the series whose $n$th term is $1/n^2.$ The terms are clearly (eventually) smaller and so the series converges.

Answer (score 1):

We will make use of $e^x>x$ for $x>0.$ Then $x>\ln x,$ for $x\ge 1.$ Thus $$0\le (\ln n) e^{-\sqrt{n}}={\ln n\over [e^{\sqrt{n}/6}]^6}\le 6^6{n\over n^{3}}={6^6\over n^2}$$

Comment: Nice bound. I like this solution